# how to configure exim for autoreplying single email account

Tags: email, exim, auto-reply

I am facing issue with exim configuration for setting auto-reply for single user email account. Currently, my exim configuration for autoreply is as follows and it causes autoreply emails to be sent to all users account instead of one:

In Routers Configuration section:

```
uservacation:
  driver = redirect
  allow_filter
  hide_child_in_errmsg
  ignore_eacces
  ignore_enotdir
  reply_transport = vacation_reply
  no_verify
  require_files = /var/spool/exim/.vacation.msg
  file = /var/spool/exim/.vacation.msg
  user = exim
  group = exim
  unseen
```

In Transport Configuration section:

```
vacation_reply:
  driver = autoreply
```

Can anyone guide me on how to configure exim auto-reply for a single email account?

Answer (score 1):

```
require_files = /var/spool/exim/.vacation.msg
```

This means that the router will decline if that file does not exist. If it does exist, it will accept the message and handle it.

```
file = /var/spool/exim/.vacation.msg
```

This is an argument to the transport, and tells it which file to use for the autoreply.

Since you're using a system-wide autoreply message, you have a global on/off switch with a global message. Clearly you don't want that.

Instead, do this:

```
uservacation:
  driver = redirect
  check_local_user
  allow_filter
  hide_child_in_errmsg
  ignore_eacces
  ignore_enotdir
  reply_transport = vacation_reply
  no_verify
  require_files = $home/.vacation.msg
  file = $home/.vacation.msg
  unseen
```

That is, drop the `user=` and `group=` configuration options, add the `check_local_user` one, and use `$home/.vacation.msg` as the file containing users' vacation messages.

This way, users can create a file `~/.vacation.msg` to create an autoreply, and they can remove it if they autoreply is no longer required.

You may also want to add the `once` configuration to your `vacation_reply` transport, so that if someone sends three emails to a person who is on vacation in short succession, they only get one vacation message. See the [documentation on the autoreply transport](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_autoreply_transport.html) for details on how to do that.